# Android ViewPager / StackView with Pages behind each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view, stackview

I try to achieve an View where i have multiple "cards" behind each other and where i could move and fling the Views away and the next "Page" shows up.

It Should be like in this Screenshot: 
[image: cardsbehindeachother]

I tried using ViewPager, but that just allows me to "Scroll" horizontal and the way i try to put the View behind each Other ( margin etc. ) doesn´t really look good.

Then i tried to use a StackView, but this doesn´t work as expected, especially the move of the items.

[image: currentwithstackview]

Is there any best practice to achieve this with an ViewPager, or do i have to build something my own?